# Importing Excel and using it for Stata do code

Tags: excel, stata

For example, suppose I have this Excel file.

[image]

Then, I am manually putting things on Excel into do file like this.

```
replace A = 1 if B>=1 & B<=6
replace A = 2 if B>=23 & B<=2
replace A = 3 if B>=3 & B<=1
replace A = 4 if B>=5 & B<=3
```

If this wasn't clear, please see this image to see what I am doing.

[image]

But there could be actually hundreds of lines.

How can write a short code which imports the Excel file, and another short code which replaces the manual codes I have written?

So the goal here is just to make my code succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `import excel` this file.  Let's suppose the headers are `A` and `B` and the import produces those as numeric variables. Then the text of a new do-file is contained within

```
 gen text = "replace A = " + string(_n) +  " if inrange(A, " + string(A) + "," + string(B) + ")"
```

which you must export and then run on your real data.

Not tested. I'd also suggest considering doing this in your favourite text editor.

Note that many of your comparisons in your example will always be false.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this but when I import excel it says "no; data in memory would be lost" because there is already pre-existing data. How can I get around this?

Comment: I tried putting the "import excel" lines to another do file, and called the do file from main do file. But this also give me "no; data in memory would be lost" error.

Comment: The intention here is that you need to create your do-file by using `import excel` on a empty dataset before you can use it on another dataset. Once you have saved your do-file, you're good to go with the real data.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Your method creates a variable "text" in dta. But actually "replace A = 4 if B>=5 & B<=3" is a command, not variable. My purpose is to succinctly replace hundreds of lines like "replace A = 4 if B>=5 & B<=3"  My purpose is to contract variable A.

Comment: Indeed. So, the contents of `text` should be saved as a do-file. Are you asking how to do that? It's just a dataset with one variable.

Comment: Yes the contents of "text" should be something that can be actually run. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: `export delimited text using mydo.do, novarnames` will export a do-file. Then remove the quote marks with a text editor, e.g. Stata's own `doedit`. Then read in your main data.

Comment: Wow! It's almost done. Thank you! Now the only thing to be done is to remove the " "  in the exported do file. Due to the " " surrounding the command, it's failing to run it. I tried to change from string to numeric but it fails because it can't be numeric anyhow. Do you know how to remove " " ?

Comment: A;ready explained: use a text editor on the file. The actions in the do-file editor in your Stata are likely to be OS-dependent.

Comment: "use a text editor on the file" Does that mean I have to do it manually? Thank you again

Comment: If manually means deleting them one by one, no. In `doedit` for replacing all characters with nothing, go `Find-Edit-Replace`. Or use `filefilter` in Stata. Or the right command in another editor or scripting language. Or find a colleague to help.